# HP printer installed and the scanner doesn't work

Tags: scanner

I've got a new printer HP Envy 5540. I downloaded and installed the printer with duplexer but I'm not able to use the scanner.

Comment: Did you install the `hplip-gui` package and use it to set up the printer? Did you encounter any issue, errors, or warning messages in the process?

Answer (score 2):

Some scanners will work straight away.  Ubuntu comes with software called SimpleScan.  If you can't find it in your applications, install it in a terminal window with `sudo apt-get install simple-scan`.

Ubuntu also comes with HPLIP which supports HP printers.

According to [this page](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/combined.html), you printer is supported.

If SimpleScan is not working for you, you may need to install HPLIP.  [Click here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html) for the downloads page, which includes instructions on how to install HPLIP.

Answer (score 2):

Open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Go to main menu and start HP Utility. It will give access to printing jobs and scan jobs as well.